# Many html files (One per page) or a huge one containing multiple pages

Tags: html, connection, request, performance

I want to know if I should have one html file per url(home,register,login,contact) i got more than 50 or should i separate them into like 5 files and get them through ?id=1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.
I want to know which method is more convenient , anyway I have understood that the second method would have to load the whole file which will be more slower than loading a single file.
But loading a single file will require more petitions and request to and from the server and the whole html files will be heavier due to i have to write a head and include all the files for each one of them

Comment: Using compression is another option you might consider.

Comment: Or you could include all the files in one and then render them on each page

Answer (score 0):

In past experience, I make sure that any components with distinct functionality is placed in its own file. I would consider distinct functionality as the examples that you listed above (home, register, login, contact, etc). On the other hand, if you are managing blog posts (or something similar), I would definitely use GET requests (i.e. ?page=1,2,3).

I have also maintained websites that have about 50-100 different pages, but it *did* use a content management system. If you feel overwhelmed, this could also be a possibility to explore.

If you do not choose to use a cms, I would recommend you to use partial files. A good example for a partial would be a header or footer. By using partials, you no longer need to replicate the same code on multiple pages (say goodbye to creating 50 navbars).